# Do I have to compile the kernel every time, even for a small change?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

In my project I configure the kernel (2.6.32) in `block/ioctl.c`.
We all know that kernel compiling and building takes few hours. Even for a small change, I'm compiling from scratch. So is there any way to compile and build only the changed file?

Comment: the first question in [KernelCustomBuild](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelCustomBuild) might help you

Comment: A few hours for a single .c file change? What commands are you using exactly and what hardware do you have?

Comment: @Mat I have to analyze the `block/ioctl.c` code. simple ex: addind `printk` function. And changing some macro kind of things

Comment: I understand that. Rebuilding after a small change in a .c file should not result in a complete rebuild, and even if it did that shouldn't take hours.

Comment: @Mat What are the steps i need to repeat. (make menuconfig, make -j4, make modules, make modules_install, make clean)

Comment: Don't reconfigure if you're not changing the configuration. **Don't** clean if you intend to rebuild with a small change.

Comment: @Mat make -j4, make modules, make modules_install are enough??

Comment: If you're not changing module interfaces, you don't even need the last two.

Comment: make -j4 is enough, right?

Comment: @SGG Can you put the commands you're using to build in your question instead of as a comment? It seems like they are the crux of the issue, and so any answers provided will refer to them.

Answer (score 10):

No, kernel compiling does not take “few hours”. Linus Torvalds said that it took him [12 minutes](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2010/04/21/how-long-would-it-have-to-take-to-compile-todays-linux-kernel-on-the-computer-that-linus-torvalds-started-19-years-ago) in the old days, and a lot less these days. Of course it depends whether you're compiling a kernel with just the drivers you need for your hardware, or a distribution kernel with all the drivers people may need — but even for a distribution kernel on a slightly elderly machine, it takes way less than an hour to do a full build.

Furthermore, if you change one file of the kernel, you don't need to do a full build. **Just run `make`** (and `make modules` if there are modules you need to recompile), and only the changed file (and the files that depend on it, if it's a header file) will be recompiled.

Comment: Even the smallest change in configuration results in entire kernel being rebuilt, and it does take hours. It always did as long as I remember (20 years and counting). It became worse when `deps` target was dropped.